# Uninstalling Extension Dependent on Another Extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, package, package.json, uninstallation

I am trying to **uninstall an extension in VSCode on which another extension is dependent**. Could anyone please assist on how this can be done?

P.S. the extension to be uninstalled has been defined in the extensionDependancies part of package.json

Comment: go to your VSC extension folder in your home directory and delete the folder containing the extension

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Can this be done programmatically or by modifying the package.json file? Can we somehow automate the process?

Comment: will the other extension work if you delete the dependency

Comment: No, the other extension was not working when I deleted the folder. However, I was able to solve the problem by using "extensionPack (and mentioned the extension within this block)" section in package.json. In this way, I was not only able to get my extension automatically installed whenever the dependent extension is installed, but also uninstall it whenever required without effecting the performance of the main extension. In other words, extensionPack gives you an option to uninstall or disable the other extension whenever needed :)

Comment: So, this post can be closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by myself. Posting the answer so that others may also benefit from it. I was able to solve the problem by using "extensionPack (and mentioned the extension within this block)" section in package.json. In this way, I was not only able to get my extension automatically installed whenever the dependent extension is installed, but also uninstall it whenever required without effecting the performance of the main extension. In other words, extensionPack gives you an option to uninstall or disable the other extension whenever needed :). My code looks like this:

"extensionPack": [
"extension identifier"
]

Reference Link:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48430